# SAP JAVA issue with package installation

Tags: java, jco

I want to create a communication between my Java web application and SAP. I used Java Connector (JCo) and have put it in library and class path. But when I try to import the package `com.sap.mw.jco.*`, the program shows a compilation error. I can see that this package is not available in `sapjco.jar`.

The issue I am facing with is, it is not allowing the import statement.

This is my code snippet

```
// basic import statements

  import com.sap.mw.jco.*;

  public void createSnippet() throws JCoException{

         JCO.Client mConnection =
         JCO.createClient("xx", // SAP client
             "xx", // userid
             "xx", // password
             "xx", // language (null for the default language)
             "xx", // application server host name
             "xx"); // system number
  JCoFunction function = dest.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_CR");
  JCoTable eqptable=function.getTableParameterList().getTable("EQU_LIST");
  eqptable.appendRow();
  eqptable.setValue("TEST1", "MY_VALUE1");
  eqptable.setValue("TEST2", "My_VALUE2");
    connection.execute(function);
 }
```

Comment: .... and the error is?

Comment: its not allowing the import statement. sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: Which version of JCO Connector you are using? Our sapjco.jar contains the class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo, so the package might be wrong.

Comment: Ok, But if I use com.sap.conn.jco.JCO it does not have the methods createClient and it shows error  in JCO.Client . Is there any alternative for this. I also tried to create an object for the class. Still does not work and shows error. Not runtime error. Jst red line in netbeans

Comment: It is not allowing the import statement because the `jar` is probably not on the class path.

Comment: no , its there. Its not showing exception in any other places excepting when I import this package. I made sure its in class path. :(

Comment: Any help in creating a single value from java to SAP is what I need. It can also be company_list

Comment: Could you post this `jar` file somewhere on the internet so that we could see its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out that com.sap.conn.jco.JCo is an alternative for com.sap.mw.jco, and the alternaive is available in sapjco.jar. This was also suggested by Seelenvirtuose.

But the classes in this jar may be slightly different than the other one.

http://www.finereporthelp.com/download/SAP/sapjco3_linux_32bit/javadoc/com/sap/conn/jco/JCo.html

Check the above link for its properties

Thank you